# Show intersection points between a curve and a line

Tags: graphics, intersection

I'm pretty new to Mathematica.
I'd like to show the intersection points in my graphic.
These are my inputs:

```
f[y_] := -10 x^2 + 4000 x;
NSolve[f[y] == 144000, x];
Plot[{f[y], 144000}, {x, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> {0, 400000}]
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to show on the plot (permanently and/or as tooltips) both the Letters and Values of the intersection points? Thanks again for your kind and qualified answers!   puckie

Answer (score 6):

Or, hitting this tiny nail with a sledge-hammer,

```
f[x_] := -10 x^2 + 4000 x;
Plot[{f[x], 144000}, {x, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> {0, 400000}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {f[#] - 144000 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]
```

[image]

See the [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) for `MeshFunctions`. It's the third example.

Comment: I don't consider this a sledgehammer at all. Everything's in the `Plot[]`, without the need for an explicit equation-solving detour.

Comment: Very simple and effective solution! Exactly what I needed as a beginner ;-)  Many Thanks!

Comment: @Narasimham. What is your "simply perfect" in reference to? What is that code about?

Comment: It was a comment in a reply to my question in Mathematica." Surface MeshFunction with independently spaced parameters". It was commented here wrongly. Thanks for pointing out the misplaced comment. Apologies caused due to my error, shall be deleting it.

Answer (score 5):

```
f[y_] := -10 y^2 + 4000 y;
sol = NSolve[f[x] == 144000, x];
Plot[{f[x], 144000}, {x, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> {0, 400000}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], (Point[{x, f[x]}] /. sol)}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With an adjustable threshold level using [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html). The [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) shows the exact values.

```
f[y_] := -10 y^2 + 4000 y;

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   (pts = Simplify[{x, f[x]} /. Solve[f[x] == t, x]]) // N,
   Plot[{f[x], t}, {x, 0, 400},
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large],
      Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts},
    ImageSize -> 360]}],
 {{t, 144000, "Threshold"}, 0, 400000, 2000,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution! Best solution!  I'll definitely use it in my plots. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
R1 = ParametricRegion[{x, -10 x^2 + 4000 x}, {{x, 0, 400}}];
R2 = ParametricRegion[{x, 144000}, {{x, 0, 400}}];

sol = Point[x /. Solve[x \[Element] R1 && x \[Element] R2, x]]
```

> Point[{{40, 144000}, {360, 144000}}]

```
RegionPlot[{R1, R2},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400000}},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], sol},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a conceptually a good solution since it involves parametrization. I'll use it when I'll be able to understand it fully (such as the meaning of \[Elements] and more...).     Many thanks!